# How to implement Jersey ContainerRequest example using org.glassfish.jersey

Tags: java, jersey

I am having some encoding issues, and am trying to implement this code...but need to use org.glassfish.jersey instead and the class structure seems very different.

https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/blob/master/rexster-server/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/rexster/filter/HeaderResponseFilter.java

Any advice appreciated, but I cant even find ContainerResponseFilter in the jersey package structure I have dependencies on, and the other dependencies seem to be in

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerResponse;
```

not the spi package in the example.

My pom looks like this:

```
<!-- JAX-RS Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JAX-RS application servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey Spring bridge to allow spring resources to be used from REST resources -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Thanks

i

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
package com.mycompany.misf.filters;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


public class HeaderResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

        public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request, ContainerResponseContext response) {
            MediaType type = response.getMediaType();
            if (type != null) {
                String contentType = type.toString();
                if (!contentType.contains("charset")) {
                    contentType = contentType + ";charset=utf-8";
                    response.getHeaders().putSingle("Content-Type", contentType);
                }
            }
        }
}
```